# WCF authentication sessions for long running applications

Tags: wcf, session, authentication

I have the following scenario.

There is a WCF .NET 4 service, hosted on IIS 7.

The service will be accessed by two kinds of clients:

1. Silverlight client (will be created later)
2. Three C# .NET 4 Console Applications (already created and tested)

To access this WCF service, I created a simple wrapper dll (I do not use Visual Studio autogenerated references to avoid updating them in multiple projects when my WCF changes, but I used autogenerated reference as a template for my wrapper).

This is how my wrapper looks like:

```
class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IMyService>,
        IMyService
```

it basically forwards all the call to base.Channel.

Now we started to think about implementing authentication. Our IIS and console apps are not guaranteed to be on the same domain, so Windows Auth is not an option. Obviously, we'll have to store username/password in the app config files for our console apps, and WCF will check it against our user database.

Per-message auth seems to be a bit too traffic and resource heavy - then we'll have to SELECT the user form our DB on each call. Our console apps are scheduled tasks and they might run all day long and issue thousands of WCF requests. So we need some kind of a authenticated user sessions.

Also I am worried about what happens if my System.ServiceModel.ClientBase disconnects unexpectedly. Currently (without any authentication), ClientBase is able to reconnect silently without any problems. I would like to keep the same behavior after I add the auth implementation. The client should be able to relogin silently without throwing any exceptions to the calling application.

As far as I understand, to allow all the ASP.NET session goodies in WCF, I have to run in ASP.Net Compatibility Mode and aslo ensure that each user has his own thread with his own Thread.CurrentPrincipal. But I have no idea how to ensure that the login will get rebewed automatically if the connection gets interrupted/server gets restarted. Do I need to add tr..catch for each method call and relogin if there is a SecurityException? Seems a bit dirty solution.

Now I can summarize two questions:

**What options do I have for authenticated auto-restorable sessions between IIS WCF service and console apps?**

**How to implement authentication session in a way, so my WCF service client wrapper is able to resume/create new session in case of a disconnect?**

**If Silverlight does not support wshttpbinding and WCF does not allow to pass user credentials over basichttpbinding (due to security reasons), then how can I implement my authentication in a secure way?**
I have found the following article:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=589
 which explains how to make Silverlight to use SSL through a custom binding, but I have no idea how to put my auth session in it so it is available for console apps, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL certificates to authenticate clients/servers within your WCF application. Actually you can use SSL cert to provide transport level security (so no message encryption/decryption business) and also utilize the cert to authenticate a client says who it is and the server says who it is.

The only drawback in this approach is that your clients will need to be made aware of your SSL Cert and depending upon your setup they might need a copy of your cert as well.

Hope this helps!